# How do I connect a LED strip to a Multiwii SE 2.5?

Tags: led, rgb-led

https://www.m.nu/neopixel/mini-skinny-neopixel-digital-rgb-led-strip-60-led-m-black-pcb-1m

I just purchased this led-strip that I plan to use with my Multiwii SE 2.5.

[image]

I power the Multiwii itself via a power distribution board where I connect a 3s LiPo battery. Now I wonder how I would wire my LED strip in order to use it with my Multiwii. I have a few smaller LiPo batteries if I need to power the LED itself (not via the 3s LiPo that powers the Multiwii) but the best solution would of course be to power them together.

I appreciate all help I can get.

Comment: Have you looked at any NeoPixel libraries yet?

Comment: yes the adafruit one. it works with arduino and since the multiwii is arduino-based i am positive it can be used with the multiwii also? i am just a bit confused on the schematic

Comment: Which part? It only needs one pin.

Comment: this is my first project so sry if i dont follow along 100 %. if i udnerstand correctly 1 pin goes to a open D-pin. but how does the led get battery? if i look at this image https://www.google.se/search?q=arduino+led+strip&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUlcC3v7HVAhWE1xQKHQxxBYQQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=983&dpr=1#imgrc=KxTVn-hmlWKCjM: it seems to get volt from the arduino itself. How do i make sure the multiwii powers the led-strip with the 3s lipo?

Comment: The 3S LiPo will burn out the strip since it only takes 5V as the specs say. So connect it to 5V.

Answer (score 1):

The led strips I've used with my Naze32 have three connection, +5VDC, GND and DATA. I'm not familiar with your FC but based on the image you provided it looks like you would use one of the two I2C ports. As long as you don't try to run too many LEDs (I've maxed out my FC with 32 LEDs no problem) the +5VDC connection should be able to power the LEDs. Obviously connect LED GND to the FC GND. You'll need to check the docs for you FC to confirm but it would make the most sense to me to connect the FC SDA to the LED DATA. The FC SCL would not be used.

NOTE: If your PDB has a +5VDC output you'd be better off using that one to power the LEDs.

In the picture with the Arduino one of the leads is providing +5VDC. I've read the suggestion for LED strips to place a capacitor across the +5VDC and GND to make it more stable but I don't and I've not had any issues. FYI, the lead to the Arduino is for GND and DATA (being driven by one of the Arduino Digital I/O Pins.